# get request attributes (sent as a list) in external .js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

I have a Servlet which sets the request attribute after getting the data from SQL (it would return a List):

```
request.setAttribute("statsRegionList", statsRegionList);
```

I have a jsp file which would have a drop down, the drop down contents are loaded by another request attribute.
Based on the drop down selection, i need to check the 'statsRegionList' and get the required result for that specific Region which matches the region selected in drop down.

After reading some forums, it was mentioned that external .js file wont be able to get the request attribute hence this would need to be set in the .jsp itself. Accordingly i have set in jsp:

```
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var regionList = <%=request.getAttribute("statsRegionList")%>;
</script>
```

However on console on IE it shows error :
SCRIPT1014: Invalid character
File: dashboard, Line: 625, Column: 47
(The invalid character is @ and that is inserted as its a List of object).

- How can i access the 'statsRegionList' in the external .js file?
- People have mentioned about Ajax, but im not sure how to use it. Any code snippet for that should be helpful.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: In a javascript part you must ensure a correct javascript syntax. `var regionList = ['region1', 'region2', 'region3' ];` would be a correct syntax. Or, if statsRegionList is a list of Objects `var regionList = [ { id: 123, name:'region1'} , { id: 125, name:'region2'} , { id: 126, name:'region3'}];` If you want to use `<%=request.getAttribute()%>` you have to ensure, the attribute contains a list in javascript syntax.  `[ '', '', '' ]`or [ {}, {}, {}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Holger you are right.

I found a solution and this is what i have done.
Since an .external js file cannot read the request attribute i have created a global variable from the jsp so that i can be used in the .js file. The request attribute was returning an ArrayList hence while creating the global variable it should also be in an Array format.

Following is the code snippet from .jsp

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var regions = [
    <c:forEach items="${statsRegionList}" var="region" varStatus="status">
    {region: '${region.name}',              Devices : '${region.DeviceCount}'}
    <c:if test="${!status.last}">
        ,
        </c:if>
    </c:forEach>
];
</script>
```

This ensures an Array of objects is created. Further in the external .js file, the global variable var regions is now accessible and can be iterated to find the required details matching with dropdown selection.
The code snipped from .jso file is below:

```
dropdownSelect = $("#regionSelect option:selected").text();
    var regionsArr = regions;
            if ($.isArray(regionsArr)){
                Object.keys(regionsArr).forEach(function (key) {
                      if(regionsArr[key]['region']== dropdownSelect){
                          var x=document.getElementById('RegionTable').rows;
                            x[0].cells[1].innerHTML=regionsArr[key]['DeviceCount'];                         
                      }
                    });
            }
```